# Why i am getting unauthorized 401 error in Spring Oauth2 while accessing token?

Tags: java, spring, curl, oauth

Hi I am implementing Spring Oauth 2 framework in my project, i am getting 401 unauthorized error when requesting for access token, below is my code.

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
        Map<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("grant_type", "password");
        map.put("client_id", "test");
        map.put("client_secret", "test");
        map.put("username", "test");
        map.put("password", "test");
        String url="http://localhost:8080/SpringOauthServer/oauth/token?grant_type={grant_type}&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&username={username}&password={password}";

        OauthToken result=restTemplate.getForObject(url, OauthToken.class,map);     
        System.out.println(result.getAccess_token());
    }


}
```

but when i use below curl command i get the access token. please help me where i am mistaking..

```
curl test:test@localhost:8080/SpringOauthServer/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d client_id=test -d client_secret=test -d username=test   -d password=test
```

Response:

```
{
   "access_token":"d83a312b-323a-40a9-bfc4-c431c40f2ca8",
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "refresh_token":"17976f94-f3b7-4e2d-8726-3d094f7b1061",
   "expires_in":43190,
   "scope":"read write trust"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but Just if some one stucked with `RestTemplate` and `OAuth2` (ex. for integration tests) this how it should work.

#### Fetching OAuth2 `access_token` using `RestTemplate`

In the above question the `grant_type=password` it means that you need to send the `client_id` and `secret` in `authorization` http header as basic authontication and the rest of the information for your request goes to the http request body as form data.

Reusing the example in the question:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        // Add the basic authentication "username:password"
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        // Adding form data
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("grant_type", "password");
        map.put("client_id", "test");
        map.put("username", "test");
        map.put("password", "test");
        map.put("scope", "read,write,trust");

        // Creating HttpEntity request with the headers and form data
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

        String url="http://localhost:8080/SpringOauthServer/oauth/token";

        // Execute the request
        ResponseEntity<String> response = 
            restTemplate
                .withBasicAuth("test", "test")
                .postForEntity(
                    url,
                    request,
                    OauthToken.class
                );

        System.out.println(result.getAccess_token());
    }
}
```

#### What Went wrong in the question:

The `curl` used in the question function completely different than the java code provided.

I will tear it down and don't foget to check the [documentation here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)

1. `curl test:test` calling `curl` using basic authentication with `test` as username and `test` as password (format `{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}`), which we did the same in our `RestTemplate` and it was missing in the question java code.
2. `localhost:8080/SpringOauthServer/oauth/token` the url used in the `curl` command is without any url parameters which we did the same in our `RestTemplate` but it was added in the question and this is wrong.
3. `-d grant_type=password -d client_id=test -d client_secret=test -d username=test   -d password=test` marking parameters with `-d` will make `curl` execute http `POST` request and send these parameters as form data in the http body which we did the same in our `RestTemplate` and it was missing in the question java code.